# how to get the image depend an article in a relation one to many?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, query-builder, symfony5

1. I'm looking for get the images of a banner
2. Every banner has many images with a relation OneToMany
3. I think I have just select the banner `where isActive = true` and get the collection of images but unfortunately not return the image

This query works in SQL but I'm stuck how to make it work fin using QueryBuilder:

```
SELECT *
FROM image
INNER JOIN banner ON image.banner_id = banner.id
WHERE banner.is_active = true
```

Code:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('i') 
            ->join('i.banner', 'b', 'on', 'i.banner_id=b.id') 
            ->andWhere('b.isActive LIKE :status') 
            ->setParameter('status',true) 
            ->getQuery(); ->execute();
```

**Banner** entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BannerRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BannerRepository::class)
 */
class Banner
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Image::class, mappedBy="banner", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->isActive=false;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Image[]
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images[] = $image;
            $image->setBanner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if ($this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getBanner() === $this) {
                $image->setBanner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive(bool $isActive): self
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Image** entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ImageRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ImageRepository::class)
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Banner::class, inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $banner;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBanner(): ?Banner
    {
        return $this->banner;
    }

    public function setBanner(?Banner $banner): self
    {
        $this->banner = $banner;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your attempt using QueryBuider with results

Comment: thank you brother i did but didnt worked   `     return
        $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
            ->join('i.banner', 'b', 'on', 'i.banner_id=b.id')
            ->andWhere('b.isActive LIKE :status')
            ->setParameter('status',true)
            ->getQuery();
        ->execute();`

Comment: Consider updating your question with your DQL query so it is readable.  Edit button in the lower left corner.  But more importantly, read the docs on how to do a proper DQL query.  It's also a bit strange that you even need to do this query.  Usually you would set things up to load the images when you load the banner.  Maybe you have an edge case where you don't want the banner but need the images.

Comment: thank you cerad i did updated my post else i would like to choose my banner from the backoffice so only the banner who has isActive true will get his images and display them in the banner  so please clarification if its possible bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed

```
    public function activeBanner()
{
    return
        $this->createQueryBuilder('image')
            ->leftJoin('image.banner', 'banner')
            ->andWhere('banner.isActive = :isActive')
            ->setParameter('isActive', true)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
}
```

*This the right queryBuilder and it should be in image Repository, hope my solution help other stack developers*